# convex combination prove

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the following:

let $V := \{v_1, \ldots,v_s \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $W:= \{w_1,\ldots,w_t \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$

I have to prove that 
$\mathrm{Conv}(V) \cap \mathrm{Conv}(W) \neq \emptyset \iff \nexists c \in \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha \in \mathbb{R} : \forall 1 \le i \le s : c^Tv_i \gt \alpha $ and $\forall 1 \le j \le t : c^Tw_i \lt \alpha $

now I tried to prove this by contraposition.
Asume 
$\exists c \in \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}: \forall 1 \le i \le s : c^Tv_i \gt \alpha $ and $\forall 1 \le j \le t : c^Tw_i \lt \alpha$ then $c$ and $\alpha$ also separate all the convex combinations of the vectors and thus $\mathrm{Conv}(V) \cap \mathrm{Conv}(W) = \emptyset$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct so far, but you also need to prove the opposite direction. Do you know the separation theorem?

Comment: is the separation theorem farkas' lemma?

Comment: I was referring to the Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem